# Keep JSON output consistent when table field is Null in Slick Play

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I've tried to not mark every field in Scala as `Option`:

```
to_date: LocalDateTime
```

But it gives `Compilation Error`:

```
 type mismatch;
 found   : None.type
 required: java.time.LocalDateTime
```

By using `Option` error is gone:

```
to_date: Option[LocalDateTime]
```

But I have faced another problem, `to_date` field is removed from JSON response:

```
UserModel.find(UserId).map {
    case Some(x) => Ok(Json.toJson(x)(userWrites))
    case None => NotFound("user not found!")
}
```

How can I keep `to_date` field in JSON response in `Scala Play framework` while using `Slick`?

Comment: In JSON, an omitted field is equivalent to a `null`-valued field. It should not make any difference. (P.S.: Avoid using snake case for Scala class properties)

Comment: @cchantep well it actually differs for our web client. The question is how should I implement it?

Comment: A well behaved client should not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `OptionHandlers` (and `JsonNaming`) for a custom `JsonConfiguration`.

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._

import java.time.LocalDateTime

case class Foo(toDate: Option[LocalDateTime])

object Foo {
  implicit val writes: OWrites[Foo] = {
    implicit def config = JsonConfiguration(
      naming = JsonNaming.SnakeCase,
      optionHandlers = OptionHandlers.WritesNull)

    Json.writes[Foo]
  }
}

Json.toJson(Foo(Some(LocalDateTime.now())))
// {"to_date":"2020-01-27T10:08:55.742106"}

Json.toJson(Foo(None))
// {"to_date":null}
```